# Natbib: \citep with same author

Tags: natbib, apa-style, multiple-citations

I am using natbib with the bibliographystyle apalike. I already figured out how to cite different works of the same author with \citet{author00,author01}, what gives me author (2000, 2001). Is it possible to do the same including page numbers, such that the result is (author 2000, p.56, 2001, p.67)? I tried to do that with \citep[]{} but that did not work.

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lewis86,
    Author = {David Kellogg Lewis},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-13 05:23:07 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-13 05:23:46 +0000},
    Publisher = {Oxford: Blackwell},
    Title = {On the Plurality of Worlds},
    Year = {1986}}

@book{lewis91,
    Author = {David Kellogg Lewis},
    Date-Added = {2016-05-22 22:59:47 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-02 01:04:04 +0000},
    Publisher = {Oxford: Basil Blackwell},
    Title = {Parts of Classes},
    Year = {1991}}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

 That works \citet{lewis86,lewis91}.

 This \citep[56,67]{lewis86,lewis91} does not.

 It gives me (Lewis, 1986, 1991, 56,67). 

 I would like to have (Lewis, 1986, 56, 1991, 67).

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, please always include something we can readily compile. Supply us with a `yourbibfile.bib` that contains the entries `lewis86` and `lewis91`. It just makes it easier.